# How to add a header if the url contain any get parameter using htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am running PHP in Apache2 server. I would like to add `header("X-Robots-Tag: noindex", true);` to my pages if the url contains any get parameters like `https://example.com/?` or `https://example.com/a.php?` or `https://example.com/a.php?key=value`. So basically, if the url contain `?` charter, the header needs to be added.

Is it possible to do it using `.htaccess` file and how to do it? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Ref: https://yoast.com/x-robots-tag-play/

## EDIT

Below are the existing rewrite codes;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^nps-benchmarks/(.*)$ http://testing.mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^agency/(.*)$ http://testing.mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/site/mod1/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^apps/(.*)$ http://testing.mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/site/mod2/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^help-each-other/(.*)$ http://testing.mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/site/mod3/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^customers-help-each-other/(.*)$ http://testing.mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/site/mod4/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ http://testing.mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/site/multilanguage/de/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^es/(.*)$ http://testing.mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/site/multilanguage/es/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ http://testing.mysite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/site/multilanguage/fr/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/themes/my-site/assets/)(css|js)(/.+)(-v\d+\.\d+)\.(min)\.(js|css)$ $1/$2/$3.$5.$6 [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

> like `https://example.com/?` or `https://example.com/a.php?`

The issue in these two instances are that the query string is *empty*, so you can't check for this using the standard `QUERY_STRING` server variable ("empty" and "not-exists" evaluate to the same thing, ie. *empty*).

However, you can check for a literal `?` (ie. query string delimiter) in the first line of the HTTP request headers, as contained in the `THE_REQUEST` Apache server variable.

In the case of the first example above, this will contain a string of the form:

```
GET /? HTTP/1.1
```

And for `/a.php?key=value`, this will be:

```
GET /a.php?key=value HTTP/1.1
```

We can use mod_rewrite to check this and set an environment variable. Then use the `header` directive to set the required `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header conditionally based on whether this env var is set.

For example, near the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Check for literal "?" in URL and set QUERY_EXISTS env var 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/.*\?
RewriteRule ^ - [E=QUERY_EXISTS:1]

# Set header if QUERY_EXISTS is set
header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex" env=QUERY_EXISTS
```

This sets the header on 2xx "OK" responses. It won't, for instance, set the header on a 404 - but 404s are not indexed anyway, so the header is redundant. However, if you specifically need to set the header on *all* (non-2xx) responses then use the `always` condition. For example:

```
# Use "always" to set on non-2xx responses as well
header always set ....
```

Note that this is also dependent on other directives you might have in your `.htaccess` file. For example, if you have existing mod_rewrite directives that cause the rewrite engine to "loop" then the env var will be renamed to `REDIRECT_QUERY_EXISTS` and you will likely need to check for this instead in the `header` directive.

Comment: Hi @MrWhite, thanks for your answer. The `RewriteEngine` rules are working fine, but the second solution is working at all. Is there anything needs to be checked? I am using MAMP.

Comment: @Alfred by "[not] working at all" - literally nothing happening? Any error? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? (Please update your question with the complete contents of the `.htaccess` file.) Have you tried the `always` _condition_ and/or `REDIRECT_QUERY_EXISTS`?

Comment: Hi @MrWhite I have updated my question with existing rewrite codes. Could you pls have a look at it?

Comment: @Alfred Due to the nature of your existing rewrite code (notably the front-controller pattern) you would need to have used the `REDIRECT_QUERY_EXISTS` env var instead in the `header` directive (as mentioned previously in my answer). Although this does depend on the nature of the initial request (whether it maps to a physical file or not). Alternatively (on Apache 2.4) you could use the `END` flag instead of `L` in 3 of your rules. And these rules would need to go at the top of the `.htaccess` file.